# Относительный и абсолютный путь include, PHP

Tags: php, html, path

У меня есть такая строчка в файле index.php

```
<?php include="folder/subfolder/file.html" ?>
```

вот древо файлов:

```
Корень---\___ Содержание Корень: index.php
   Folder ---\___
   Subfolder  ---\
--------------------------------
Содержание subfolder:
image.jpg | file.html
```

В принципе понятно что я подключаю файл. Внутри подключаемого файла есть вот что:

```
<img src="image.img" />
```

Но вот незадача, include или require встраивает файл тем самым относительный путь использовать нельзя  ведь если в подключаемом файле есть относительный путь то он автоматически не найдет файл так как будет искать файл относительно index.php в корне.

Что делать, мне очень нужен относительный путь а он не работает просто почему он не переводит его в абсолютный. есть способы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте магическую константу `__DIR__`

```
<img src="<?php echo __DIR__ ; ?>/image.img" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал о такой.

Comment: Она получается константа относительно пути.